# Dark+ Theme in VSCode changes after I install Dart extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I am trying to use Dark+ (default theme) theme in VSCode. Every time I try to use the theme, theme colors change to something different for variables, and the  @override. Both become light-blue in color (as in the picture.[image: variables changes color after adding Dart extension])
I have searched and tried everything, including removing and re-installing VSCode itself (and lost my other settings.json on the way!) My question is how to use the Dark+ theme along with the Dart extension?
I use the latest versions of both Flutter and Dart on a Linux (LinuxMint) machine.

Answer (score 1):

After extensive search, I could find the solution that may help others who may face such a problem.
add

`"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false,`

to your `settings.json` file.